# Calculating the length of a curve $(x,x^2)$ for $x\in [0,2]$ using the Hausdorff measure of the set $A=\{(x,x^2)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x\in[0,2] \}$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, arc-length, hausdorff-measure

Let $A$ be the set of points given by the graph of $f(x) = x^2$ on the interval $[0,1]$:
$$
A = \{(x,x^2) \in \mathbb{R}^2\bigg| \ x \in[0,2] \}.
$$

I want to calculate the length of this one dimensional curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using the Hausdorff measure. Using the standard method of calculating this length via an integral with an arc-length parameterization I (meaning WolframAlpha) get:

$$
I(A) = \int_0^2 \sqrt{1 + \frac{dy}{dx}^2}dx  = \int_0^2 \sqrt{1 + (2x)^2} dx = \sqrt{17} + \frac{1}{4} \sinh^{-1}(4) \approx 4.64678.
$$

The Hausdorff measure is defined as follows. Let $\alpha_m$ be the Lebesgue measure of the closed unt ball in $\mathbb{R}^m$. For $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, the $m$-dimesnsional Hausdorff measure of $B$ is defined as:
$$
H^m(B) = \lim_{\delta \to 0 } \inf \bigg\{\sum_j \alpha_m \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^m (\text{diam}(S_j))^m \bigg| B \subset \bigcup_j S_j, \ \text{diam}(S_j) < \delta \bigg\}
$$

So in my case I want the one-dimensional Hausdorff measure of the set $A$ I defined earlier and the definition becomes:
$$
H^1(A) = \lim_{\delta \to 0 } \inf \bigg\{\sum_j (\text{diam}(S_j)) \bigg| A \subset \bigcup_j S_j, \ \text{diam}(S_j) < \delta \bigg\}
$$

I believe this should agree with earlier result obtained with the arc-length integral and we should get:
$$
H^1(A) = I(A) \sqrt{17} + \frac{1}{4} \sinh^{-1}(4) \approx 4.64678.
$$

But I have no idea how we can evaluate this Hausdorff measure of $A$ from the definition. It seems extremely complicated, and this is about the simplest example I can think of!

How do we pick the sets $S_j$ whose union covers $A$ and that have diameter less than $\delta$ - there is an infinite number of possibilities here..and then we have to take an infinum, followed by taking a limit. How can we evaluate it?

Comment: Why the `\Bigg|`s? (I corrected the one in the title.)

Comment: "How do we pick the sets Sj whose union covers A and that have diameter less than δ - there is an infinite number of possibilities here..and then we have to take an infinum, followed by taking a limit" Hmmm, yes all these are true -- which is why nobody would compute the length of the arc using this method. :-)

Comment: @Did Oh I used the big vertical line out of habit!

Comment: @Did Ok, I see from Christian's answer that he mentions there is a theorem that relates the one-dimensional Hausdorff measure to a length integral which I assume is what you are hinting at in your second comment. With that in mind, what 'good' is the Hausdorff measure..when we want to evaluate the measure of some $m$ dimensional set in $n$ dimensions would we *ever* use the Hausdorff measure or is there always an alternative related approach as in the one-dimensional case? And if there is always another easier/better approach, why do we care about the Hausdorff measure at all?

Comment: We do care, because there are subsets of the plane that are **much more complicated** to "measure" than the graphs of regular functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is a general theorem saying that for a smooth arc $\gamma$ the one-dimensional Hausdorff measure of this arc is equal to its length computed via an integral.

In the case at hand the length $L(\gamma)$ of the arc
$$\gamma:\quad x\mapsto(x,x^2)\qquad(0\leq x\leq 2)$$
is defined as
$$L(\gamma):=\sup_{\cal P}\sum_{k=1}^{N_{\cal P}}\sqrt{(x_k-x_{k-1})^2+(x_k^2-x_{k-1}^2)^2}\ ,\tag{1}$$
where the $\sup$ is taken over all partitions ${\cal P}$ of the $x$-interval $[0,2]$.  It is  proven in calculus 102 that this $L(\gamma)$ is equal to the integral you have calculated.

On the other hand arguments similar to those used in the proof of $(1)$, but "the other way around", show that $H^1(\gamma)$, as defined in the question, is equal to the same integral.

Comment: Ok thanks! I am now left wondering what 'good' is the Hausdorff measure  (repeating my comment above) ..when we want to evaluate the measure of some $m$ dimensional set in $n$ dimensions would we *ever* use the Hausdorff measure or is there always an alternative related approach as in the one-dimensional case? And if there is always another easier/better approach, why do we care about the Hausdorff measure at all?